# flutter new web project not showing in Android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new with Flutter, and I am trying to view my new project with Android Emulator. I've installed Dart, Flutter, and Android Studio correctly, but when I try to start the project in Visual Studio (without and with debugging mode), and choosing the correct emulator I get the following error:

> Your launch config references a program that does not exist. If you
> have problems launching, check the "program" field in your
> ".vscode/launch.json" file.

I have read in the documentation that it is possible to fix this by adding:

```
  "program": "lib/main.dart",
```

instead of:

```
program  : bin/main.dart
```

But still does not work.

Comment: Can you share the output of `flutter doctor`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question says you are going to run Flutter web project in android emulator.
From this, I am guessing that you are using Flutter beta version. With that version, you can't run your project on android emulator.

Second, to run Flutter project on VSCode, you need to add `launch.json` file for some configuration like this.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter - Current",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.329], locale en-GB)
 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)